# decode not working properly in python 2.7

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a program that uses web crawling to retrive the stock info but somehow the program is not able to decode the webpage. I want this code to be strictly for python 2.

```
import urllib2
import re

stock=str(raw_input("Give the stock name"))

url = "https://www.google.com/finance?q="

req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = str(response.read())

data1 = data.decode('utf-8')

print(data)
m = re.search('meta itemprop="price"',data1)
start = m.start()
end = start+50
newString = data1[start:end]
m=re.search('content="',newString)
start = m.end()
newString1 = newString[start:]
m = re.search("/",newString1)
start=0
end=m.end()-3
final= newString1[0:end]

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but a suggestion. Try using the beautifulsoup python library. Its has many available functions for web scraping and crawling plus other functionalities and handles most of what you are trying to achieve in your question plus is compatible with all python versions.

Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 for the documentation.

A sample example is;

```
import BeautifulSoup, urllib

url = 'http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup('a')

print x
```

Comment: urllib is not compaitable with python 2